# change permissions on ROOT folder

Tags: powershell

kind of a weird question - I have the below script that changes permissions and works fine. However, it does it on the folders that are BELOW the ROOT folder I targeted...but does not change perms on the ROOT folder itself!

So, how do I change the permissions on the ROOT folder and subfolders...

```
$ROOT_FOLDER = "\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR"

Get-ChildItem $ROOT_FOLDER -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
    $FullName = $_.FullName
    $ACL_LIST = Get-Acl $FullName
    $ACL_LIST.access | ForEach-Object  {
        if ($_.IdentityReference -eq "BFG\ACL-CHANGE-ALL-ROBS-UATW9GAR")
        {
            write-host $FullName -ForegroundColor white -NoNewline
            $colRights1 = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles" 
            $permission = "BFG\ACL-CHANGE-ALL-ROBS-UATW9GAR",$colRights1,"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow” 
            $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission 
            $ACL_LIST.SetAccessRule($accessRule)  
            $ACL_LIST | Set-Acl $FullName
            write-host " : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions"

        }

    }
}
```

output I get:

```
\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR\251 : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions
\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR\251\000 : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions
\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR\251\000\Adobe AIR : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions
\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR\251\000\SRV : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions
\\SERVER\d$\files\uatw9rar\W7_ADOBE_AIR\251\000\Adobe AIR\Versions : set with 'Modify,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles' permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ChildItems` does what it says on the tin. It will iterate through all contained items give a `-path`, in your case `-recurse` with keep going until it hits a dead end.

What you can do is build up an array of directories first by combining `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` like so:

```
$directories = @(Get-Item -path $ROOT_FOLDER | Where-object {$_.psIscontainer})
$directories += Get-ChildItem -path $ROOT_FOLDER -recurse | Where-object {$_.psIscontainer}

$directories | ForEach-Object {Do your stuff here}
```